# Google Play Music remove pinned offline music quicker 

Tags: google-play-music

When starting with the Google Music (or Play Music) app I've selected quite a few albums for offline syncing over time. Is there a way to quickly get an overview of my offline music and remove it?

When having the "offline music" view filter on I see tons of songs that I've to deselect one-by-one and I don't seem to find out how to do a multiple select or any other way to speed up this proces.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a file manager, you can browse to /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music and just delete everything you want from there.

Comment: But there all songs have a number? How would I know which number is which and how does Google Music deal with suddenly missing music? I presume the app has some sort of internal DB?

Comment: If the songs aren't there then Google Play will just download what it needs again. The DB won't get messed up by the deletion.

Comment: That is already great, though, the issue remains that this is not a crazy fast/easy way of creating more space as the files have random numbers as names and thus are hard to identify.